Why is there no antiforgery token rendered?
Context:
I'm building an application using .NET 8 Blazor AUTO.
I have 2 projects (server & client), all of my components + my MainLayout are within my client project.
Problem statement
I like to load data that is relevant to all pages within my MainLayout. Whenever I include this code (& my guess would be perform the StateHasChanged();) my signout functionality returns an error.
The antiforgery token is not being rendered on the client:
<form action="Account/Logout" method="post" b-u3usycoz9l=""><!--!--><!--!-->
                <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="" b-u3usycoz9l=""><!--!-->
                <!--!--><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link" b-u3usycoz9l=""><i class="fa-light fa-right-from-bracket" b-u3usycoz9l=""></i> Sign out
                </button></form>

MainLayout Data retrieval
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        // RETRIEVE DATA from service


        Loading = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

Sign out functionality
    <Authorized>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <form action="Account/Logout" method="post">
                <AntiforgeryToken />
                <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@currentUrl" />
                <button type="submit" class="nav-link">
                    <span class="bi bi-arrow-bar-left-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Logout
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </Authorized>

The error
AntiforgeryValidationException: The required antiforgery request token was not provided in either form field "__RequestVerificationToken" or header value "RequestVerificationToken".
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(HttpContext httpContext)

BadHttpRequestException: Invalid anti-forgery token found when reading parameter "string returnUrl" from the request body as form.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory+Log.InvalidAntiforgeryToken(HttpContext httpContext, string parameterTypeName, string parameterName, Exception exception, bool shouldThrow)

Program.cs (server)
I'm including my program.cs configuration. I have tried every possible sorting order, always the same error. (I don't have any registration in my client project program.cs)
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseAntiforgery();

Whenever I move my data retrieval away from my MainLayout to every individual page (which I don't like to do) and delete the StateHasChanged() in my MainLayout the sign-out functionality simply works.
I've been googling for days but can't find any relevant information / solutions. Anyone can help me out? Much appreciated!

did you find a solution

I made the decision to go back to pure Blazor Webassembly. Going to keep away from this auto mode which is more confusing to me then anything else.
